# How to get tensor with embeddings weights from tf.feature_column.embedding_column?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I'm using `tf.feature_column.embedding_column` for model training.

After training I would like to get tensor with learned weights, how to do that in TensorFlow 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which API you are using, you can get the weights within the Estimator after passing `embedding_column` to chosen estimator, eg `tf.estimator.DNNClassifier` and retrieving estimator's variables:

```py
columns =
    tf.feature_column.embedding_column(categorical_column, dimension=<int>)

estimator = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(feature_columns=columns, ...)
estimator.train(input_fn, steps)

# ...

variable_names = estimator.get_variable_names()
for variable_name in variable_names:
    variable_value = classifier.get_variable_value(variable_name)
    print(name, repr(variable_value), print(variable_value))
```

In my example model I can find eg. those weights variables with weights array data:

- `'dnn/input_from_feature_columns/input_layer/genome_embedding/embedding_weights'`

```
[[-0.40976372 -0.23827374 -0.21227716 ...  0.5545821  -0.39704907
  -0.20433223]
 [-0.09768832  0.10465638 -0.18054526 ...  0.18183397 -0.14111575
  -0.01054266]
 [-0.29748577 -0.32883364  0.16298445 ...  0.04143892  0.19518057
  -0.14070898]
 [ 0.2233038   0.17278355 -0.01609583 ...  0.08676444  0.02549041
  -0.14985928]
 [ 0.13314098  0.01100806 -0.09716068 ...  0.1540673  -0.18161789
   0.28014034]
 [-0.00838758 -0.02734249  0.00528394 ... -0.05435016 -0.01493737
  -0.00866621]]
```

- `'dnn/input_from_feature_columns/input_layer/genome_embedding/embedding_weights/t_0/Adagrad'`

```
[[1.44397810e-01 1.19423054e-01 1.70357212e-01 ... 5.23897648e-01
  2.42158890e-01 1.05686426e-01]
 [8.75400330e+02 9.28867065e+02 5.93030273e+02 ... 9.08153442e+02
  9.01593262e+02 9.31873169e+02]
 [4.71744843e+02 5.78124268e+02 6.89979248e+02 ... 6.74259155e+02
  1.01136127e+03 6.12792297e+02]
 [5.25797363e+02 5.61125427e+02 5.83498657e+02 ... 6.07227112e+02
  8.72517883e+02 5.61017639e+02]
 [8.31141296e+02 8.37725464e+02 5.51519714e+02 ... 7.87189575e+02
  8.35132019e+02 8.92976868e+02]
 [1.00000001e-01 1.00000001e-01 1.00000001e-01 ... 1.00000001e-01
  1.00000001e-01 1.00000001e-01]]
```

Hope this would be helpfull, let know in comments if this won't work for you.